# JavaFX AnchorPane scaling

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scaling

I'm having trouble scaling components inside of the anchor pane relating to the size of the anchor pane.
What I want to achieve is a rectangle 50% x 50% the size of the anchor pane positioned at the center.

I'm currently trying to achieve this with this code:

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane centerPane = new AnchorPane();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(rect, .25 * centerPane.getHeight());
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(rect, .25 * centerPane.getHeight());
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(rect, .25 * centerPane.getHeight());
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(rect, .25 * centerPane.getHeight());

        Scene scene = new Scene(centerPane, 320, 240);

        stage.setTitle("Anchor Pane Scaling test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    
}
```

However I get no rectangle displayed.

I want to know if there's a way to fix this approach or if there's a better way of scaling Nodes inside panes in general that I should try.

Comment: The concept of scaling is often confused with the concept of layout resizing.  For scaling, *everything* gets bigger or smaller when scaled up or down via a [scale transform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/transformation-types.htm#BABDEBGA).  But when a layout is resized, layout resizing logic adjusts the size and position of the nodes but usually does not scale them.  A text input control scaled up will have larger text. A text input control that is layout resized will have more letters, not larger letters.  All nodes are scalable, but not all are resizable.

Comment: In terms of API, you can see if a node is resizable by checking [`isResizable()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#isResizable()).  For scaling you can use [scaleX/Y/Z properties](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#scaleXProperty()) or apply [transforms](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#Transformations), specifically [Scale](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Scale.html).  To have a scaled size considered in layout calculations, wrap the node in a `Group`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons your code doesn't work:

1. `Rectangle` (and all `Shape`) instances are not [*resizable*](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#isResizable). This means a parent (such as `AnchorPane`) can not resize these nodes (specifically, `Rectangle.resize()` is a no-op).
2. You are calling `centerPane.getHeight()` before the pane has been laid out. This means its `height` (and `width`) will be zero at that time. You really need to re-do the layout any time that width and height change.

JavaFX supports a collection of `Pane` subclasses which manage layout.  (See, for example, [this tutorial](https://edencoding.com/javafx-layouts/), or the [API docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html)) for details.) Typically, if you require a layout strategy that is not supported by one of these layout panes, then you should define your own by subclassing `Region` or `Pane`. You should, at a minimum, override the `layoutChildren()` method, along with the methods to compute the min/pref/max width and height.

Whether or not your actual use case warrants the amount of coding needed to do this is not clear from your question. However, here is a quick example of a container pane that centers its content and has a configurable value for determining what (linear) proportion of its size its content should occupy.

```
package org.jamesd.examples.centeringpane;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class CenteringPane extends Region {

    private final Node content ;
    private DoubleProperty sizeProportion = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);

    public CenteringPane(Node content) {
        this.content = content;
        getChildren().add(content);
        sizeProportion.addListener(obs -> requestLayout());
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        if (content.isManaged()) {
            double w = getWidth();
            double h = getHeight();
            double targetWidth = (w - snappedLeftInset() - snappedRightInset()) * getSizeProportion();
            double targetHeight = (h - snappedTopInset() - snappedBottomInset()) * getSizeProportion();
            double x = (w - targetWidth) / 2;
            double y = (h - targetHeight) / 2;
            content.resizeRelocate(snapPositionX(x), snapPositionY(y), snapSizeX(targetWidth), snapSizeY(targetHeight));
        }
    }

    public double getSizeProportion() {
        return sizeProportion.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty sizeProportionProperty() {
        return sizeProportion;
    }

    public void setSizeProportion(double sizeProportion) {
        this.sizeProportion.set(sizeProportion);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return snappedLeftInset() + snappedRightInset() + content.prefWidth(height) / getSizeProportion();
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return snappedTopInset() + snappedBottomInset() + content.prefHeight(width) / getSizeProportion();
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMinWidth(double height) {
        return snappedLeftInset() + snappedRightInset() + content.minWidth(height) / getSizeProportion();
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMinHeight(double width) {
        return snappedTopInset() + snappedBottomInset() + content.minHeight(width) / getSizeProportion();
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMaxWidth(double height) {
        return snappedLeftInset() + snappedRightInset() + content.maxWidth(height) / getSizeProportion();
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
        return snappedTopInset() + snappedBottomInset() + content.maxHeight(width) / getSizeProportion();
    }

    @Override
    public Orientation getContentBias() {
        return content.getContentBias();
    }
}
```

Here is a quick test case:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.centeringpane;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.BLUE));
        CenteringPane centeringPane = new CenteringPane(pane);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(centeringPane);
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 1, 0.5);

        centeringPane.sizeProportionProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());
        HBox controls = new HBox(5, slider);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setTop(controls);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

@James_D pointed out all of the reasons not to use `Rectangle`. Here is an example that uses `Pane` and `GridPane`.

### Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints25Percent = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints25Percent.setPercentWidth(25);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints50Percent = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints50Percent.setPercentWidth(50);
        root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(columnConstraints25Percent, columnConstraints50Percent, columnConstraints25Percent);
        
        RowConstraints rowConstraints25Percent = new RowConstraints();
        rowConstraints25Percent.setPercentHeight(25);
        RowConstraints rowConstraints50Percent = new RowConstraints();
        rowConstraints50Percent.setPercentHeight(50);
        root.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowConstraints25Percent, rowConstraints50Percent, rowConstraints25Percent);
        
        Pane centerPane = new Pane();
        centerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        root.add(centerPane, 1, 1);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 700);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]